# String is not printing with doublequotes in javscript?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm building a `todo` program in node. It prints the status of tasks remaining and completed using following code:-

```
'Report':function(){
    var remaining=fs.readFileSync(source,'utf-8').split('\n').length-1;
    var completed=fs.readFileSync(dest,'utf-8').split('\n').length-1;
    var day=ReturnDate();
    var text=day+` Pending : `+remaining.toString()+` Completed : `+completed.toString();
    console.log(text);
}
```

`ReturnDate` returns formatted date.

```
const ReturnDate=function(){
    const dateObj=new Date();
    const month=String(dateObj.getMonth()).padStart(2,'0');
    const day = String(dateObj.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    const year = dateObj.getFullYear();
    var res=year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
    return res;
}
```

When i run it in console it generates:-

```
2020-11-21 Pending : 1 Completed : 2
```

But when i run tests, it is failing,

```
  ● report pending & completed todos

expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: StringContaining "2020-12-21 Pending : 1 Completed : 2"
Received: "2020-11-21 Pending : 1 Completed : 2
"

  216 |   let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("report")).toString("utf8");
  217 |
> 218 |   expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
      |                    ^
  219 | });
  220 |

  at Object.<anonymous> (todo.test.js:218:20)
```

I do not know why the second double quote is shifting to next line even though i'm not using any new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd double quote is not the problem, these two strings are not equal.

First has date `2020-12-21` but the receieved string has date `2020-11-21`. That is why the tests are failing.